# How to transpose messy Excel worksheets to Pandas DataFrame using read_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am in the process of migrating legacy data that has unfortunately been stored in Excel, to a database. I have had success using pandas to collect data from other sheets in my set of Excel workbooks, but I am having trouble wrapping my brain around this situation.

As it stands, I have 26 Excel workbooks and I need to extract data from 190 different sheets that all have the same formatting:

```
| Effective Date: | MM/DD/YYYY | (blank column) | Effective Date: | MM/DD/YYYY |
|-----------------|------------|----------------|-----------------|------------|
| Account         | Allocation |                |Account          | Allocation |
| ###########     | X.X%       |                |###########      | X.X%       |
| ###########     | X.X%       |                |###########      | X.X%       |
| ###########     | X.X%       |                |###########      | X.X%       |
```

Each worksheet can have several pairs of these columns and can have a different number of accounts, and the effective date is always different. For historical purposes, I need to collect all the data from every single sheet. I am trying to transpose this data to get it into the following format:

```
|Client Name      | Schedule Name  |Effective Date |Account          |Allocation     |
|-----------------|----------------|---------------|-----------------|---------------|
|Client A         |Some Schedule A |01/01/2017     |###########      |X.X%           |
|Client A         |Some Schedule B |01/01/2020     |###########      |X.X%           |
|Client B         |Some Schedule A |01/01/2017     |###########      |X.X%           |
|Client B         |Some Schedule B |01/01/2019     |###########      |X.X%           |
|Client B         |Some Schedule C |01/01/2022     |###########      |X.X%           |
```

(note: the "schedule name" is the name of the worksheet the data is coming from, and the client name comes from the name of the workbook)

I have created a dictionary with the client names and workbook paths (client_workbooks), as well as a dictionary that stores the name of the sheets that need to be scraped for each client (schedule_name). My instinct is to loop through the files and sheets like this:

```
for k, v in client_workbooks.items():
    with pd.ExcelFile(v) as reader:
        for x in schedule_name[k]: 
            sheet = pd.read_excel(reader, sheet_name=x)
```

However, this returns a complete mess of data with thousands of empty rows and mismatched information. I am not sure if I need to be using pd.concat or pd.append to get this data into a new format.

Can anyone help me re-think the approach to this so I can transpose it to the format outlined above?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added some sample files at this [LINK](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14LuiNIkVBo6MReWqWFvCtWWfmRrtkhnW?usp=sharing) for those who requested some sample data! Thanks so much.

Comment: First, do one sheet only and get that in the format you want.  Splitting the two-column format into two datafames shouldn't be hard, nor should adding a date column or a "schedule name" column.  Once you can do that for each of the sheets ON THEIR OWN, you can start thinking about how to combine them.

Comment: Do you have a sample that you can share? If it safe to do so, you can share a download link

Comment: @sammywemmy I added a link to some sample data - thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

As commented, develop a generalized method that processes one worksheet, then run the method on all files. Additionally, given the format you show, you would need to use non-defaults to the arguments of [**`pandas.read_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) such as `header`, `skiprows`, `nrow`, etc.

Below is untested code so you may need to adjust according to actual data. It is assumed sheet data all starts at `A1` cell.

```py
def extract_sheet_data(xlfile, client, schedule):
    # RETRIEVE DATES
    dates_df = pd.read_excel(xlfile, sheet_name=schedule, header=None, nrow=1)

    # PARSE ACCOUNT DATA
    account_raw_df = pd.read_excel(xlfile, sheet_name=schedule, skiprows=1)
    # COMBINE BOTH COLUMN PAIRS
    account_df = (
        pd.concat([
            acount_raw_df[["Account", "Allocation"]].assign(
                **{"Effective Date": dates_df.at[0, 1]}
            ),
            acount_raw_df[["Account.1", "Allocation.1"]].assign(
                **{"Effective Date": dates_df.at[0, 4]}
            )
        ]).assign(
            **{"Client Name": client, "Schedule Name": schedule}
        )
    )

    return account_df

# ITERATE THROUGH ALL CLIENT WORKBOOKS AND SCHEDULE SHEETS
df_list = []
for k, v in client_workbooks.items():
    with pd.ExcelFile(v) as reader:
        for x in schedule_name[k]: 
            df_list.append(extract_sheet_data(xlfile=reader, client=k, schedule=x))

final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your excel, and it seems consistent in that every sheet has an allocation, account, and the first row is effective date and the dates. It is inconsistent because there are different numbers of columns for each sheet. One way to resolve this is to read the data where each cell is represented in a row; [xlsx_cells](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.xlsx_cells) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) offers this; you can then reshape the data accordingly, based on row and column position - currently [xlsx_cells](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.xlsx_cells) is in dev, so you have to install it from the repo:

```py
# xlsx_cells is currently in dev, 
# so use the form below to install pyjanitor
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from janitor import xlsx_cells

def extract_data(frame):
    effective_date = (frame
                      # get the first row, and only dates
                     .loc[frame.row.eq(1) & frame.is_date, ['value', 'column']]
                     .rename(columns = {'value':'Effective Date'})
                    )

    return (frame
              # get rows after the second
              # check the number format
              # and create the account column
             .loc[frame.row.gt(2), ['value', 'column', 'number_format']]
             .assign(account = lambda df: np.where(df.number_format.eq('General'), df.value, np.nan))
              # syntactic sugar for pd.Series.ffill
              # to align account with allocation
             .fill_direction(account = 'down')
             .loc[lambda df: df.number_format.ne('General')]
             .rename(columns = {'value':'allocation'})
              # align with effective date on the columns
             .merge(effective_date, on='column')
             .drop(columns=['column', 'number_format'])
            )
```

Read in all the sheets:

```py
frame = xlsx_cells("/home/sam/sample_data.xlsx", include_blank_cells = False)
```

Iterate through each dataframe and apply the `extract_data` function:

```py
frame = {key : df.pipe(extract_data) for key, df in frame.items()}
frame = pd.concat(frame, names=['Schedule Name']).reset_index(level = 'Schedule Name')

frame.head()


       Schedule Name    allocation  account Effective Date
0   Schedule X_Project1 0.186   37250233292 2016-11-01 00:00:00
1   Schedule X_Project1 0.114   95838293474 2016-11-01 00:00:00
2   Schedule X_Project1 0.064   14549681409 2016-11-01 00:00:00
3   Schedule X_Project1 0.18    37363837761 2016-11-01 00:00:00
4   Schedule X_Project1 0.063   53977980318 2016-11-01 00:00:00
```

You can easily extend this to all the worksheets. Have a go and let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Thank you so much. Currently having a really hard time adding xlsx_cells from the repo, so I have to do more research on how to get that properly set up. Looking forward to trying this out when it's running. I noticed the original files with the allocation schedules are actually XLSM and not XLSX so I'm wondering if that has something to do with my problem.

Comment: What's the error message when you install?